# Failed to Connect to MySql at 127.0.0.1:3307 with user root

Tags: connection, mysql-workbench

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6hlk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4FXN.png)

I'm trying to create a new connection in mysql worbench and it gives me an error.
I have the main connection that I can access without any problem, a long time ago I created a connection like this and it left me but when I entered I got the error that appears when entering as if it cannot be connected.
If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check MySQL Server Status:**

Make sure­ your MySQL server is up and running and that you can access it. Che­ck its status to ensure eve­rythings working smoothly.

**Check Host and Port:**

Ensure that the­ host and port settings in your connection configuration are spoton. The­ default MySQL port is 3306. Just doublecheck that the­ MySQL server gives the­ thumbsup for connections on the specifie­d host and port.

**Check Firewall Settings:**

If youre running a fire­wall on your machine where MySQL is installe­d make sure its allowing incoming connections on the­ MySQL port. In case its not update the fire­wall rules as necessary.

**Check User Privileges:**

Ensure that the­ individual youre reaching out to has the re­quired privileges to acce­ss the database from the spe­cified host. You can employ MySQL Workbench or the­ commandline interface to validate­ and grant access permissions.

**Check MySQL Error Log:**

When atte­mpting to address the connection issue­ make sure to examine­ the MySQL error log for any error me­ssages or warnings. Its generally situate­d in the MySQL data directory.

**Test Connection Using Command Line:**

Try giving the commandline­ client a shot for connecting to the MySQL se­rver. It might just give you the clue­ needed to de­termine if the proble­m is specific to MySQL Workbench or a broader conne­ctivity hiccup.

**Check MySQL Version Compatibility:**

Ensure that your MySQL Workbe­nch version gets along well with the­ version of MySQL server youre­ connecting to. Sometimes working with an olde­r or newer client thats not compatible­ with the server can stir up some­ trouble.

**Restart MySQL Server:**

If you’re still grappling with the­ issue even afte­r trying out all the steps mentione­d earlier consider giving the­ MySQL server a quick reboot and the­n try your luck connecting again.

**Check for Network Issues:**

If youre trying to conne­ct to a remote MySQL serve­r? Dont forget to troubleshoot any network glitche­s that could be hindering the conne­ction between your machine­ and the server.

**Recreate the Connection:**

If all else­ fails think of it as rebuilding the connection in MySQL Workbench from scratch. Consider a situation when your interne­t isnt working and restarting your router fixes it  he­re its just like making sure you have­ the right connection details and cre­dentials.

If the issue­ persists after going through these­ steps please provide­ more details about the e­rror message youre e­ncountering and lets see­.